# Access specific properties of an unknown type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, textbox

I am looking to test all of the controls on a form, and if a given control is a TextBox, I want to record the MaxLength property of that control. I am able to test each control like so:

```
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                // Get the MaxLength property.
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out how to get the control's MaxLength property, as it is specific to a TextBox and not in ctrl's property list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `ctrl` to `TextBox`:

```
TextBox textBox = ctrl as TextBox;
if (textBox != null) {
    ...
}
```

The [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) will try to cast its operand to the specified type, and returns `null` if the operand is of a different type.

[This pattern is faster than checking `is`, then casting separately](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx).

Comment: It's not *always* faster in my experience - at least not measurably so, even in millions of iterations. I think it depends on what type you're testing for.

Comment: @Jon: I've always wondered about that.  Do you have more details?

Comment: Only that when I tested it for object to string recently it was basically neck and neck. I suspect that is influenced by string being a sealed class. Non-sealed classes and interfaces almost certainly change things significantly. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I do have a question, however. Let's say that I want to check all of the controls on a form, and if I stumble across a TabControl, iterate through the pages and perform some operation. In that case, won't I still need something like "if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TabControl))" since other types of controls won't have TabPages, but "if (tabControl != null)" would evaluate to true even after the cast? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        var result = ((TextBox)ctrl).MaxLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: That link really has nothing to do with his answer. He's only accessing the MaxLength value, so it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Rob, it is valid code, but both doing a `is` check and then the following cast is better written with the `as` operator as in SLaks answer.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks says, you need to cast in some way. You may want to use the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        int max = tb.MaxLength;
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you're not doing anything else with non-textbox controls, you may want to consider using LINQ:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    int max = tb.MaxLength;
    // ...
}
```